# Dynamically add language/locale using angular-google-maps?

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I want to dynamically add language using angular-google-maps. Language is dynamic, and can retrieve from screen.locale. My application is locale based and everything change when user select different language. Issue is google maps cities are not changing based on language also, I didn't find any locale tag in ui-gmap-google-map. Can I do using below code snippet?

I am using Angular v1:

```
  <ui-gmap-google-map 
    center="question.map.initialcoords"  
    zoom="question.map.zoom" 
    pan="false" 
    control="question.map.control"
    options="question.map.options"
    >

      <ui-gmap-markers 
        idKey="'id'"
        models="question.markers" 
        coords="'coords'" 
        fit="true" 
        icon="'iconpath'"
        options="'options'" 
        >
        <ui-gmap-windows isIconVisibleOnClick="true" show="showwindow()">
          <div ng-non-bindable>
            {{title}}
          </div>
        </ui-gmap-windows>
      </ui-gmap-markers>
  </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to replace the language you should at first delete the script and google maps,
then generate it again and wait a while till it's reloaded
you can do it like that:

```
async loadScript() {
var oldScript = document.getElementById("agmGoogleMapsApiScript");
if (oldScript !== null) {
  oldScript.parentNode.removeChild(oldScript);
  delete google.maps;
}
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.async = true;
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
v=3&key={{YourApiKey}}&region=israel&language= 
{{language}}';
script.id = "agmGoogleMapsApiScript";
document.body.appendChild(script);
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}
```

then you should reload the agm-core map, you can do it by stepping out of the component.

finally, create the view which will trigger that function.

don't forget to declare google, like that:

```
declare var google: any;
```

worked for me, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This project is No longer actively maintained

[https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps][1]

**Use AGM to work with google Map. It is very easy to use.**

[https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started][2]

**ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string = 'My first AGM project';
  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>

<!-- this creates a google map on the page with the given lat/lng from -->
<!-- the component as the initial center of the map: -->
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

But still if you want to use please use below code.
Use coords attribute inorder to set latitude,longitude
(coords="marker.coords")

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
        <ui-gmap-marker coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" events="marker.events" idkey="marker.id">
        </ui-gmap-marker>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>

$scope.marker = {
      id: 0,
      coords: {
        latitude: 40.1451,
        longitude: -99.6680
      }
```